# Elliptic Dirichlet problems with measure boundary data

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Can you point out any references on the Dirichlet problem for divergence-type elliptic operators with a Radon measure as boundary data?

Comment: did you try looking at the various papers by Laurent Véron.

Comment: @Math604 Which ones?

Comment: i not sure...but that whole group seems to have a ton of papers on stuff like this..

Comment: @Math604 I see. There is also a book on the topic by that author. You should add some details and make your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it.